# How can I get response ajax correctly?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am learning C# and jQuery AJAX. I'm currently having a problem where I cannot get Ajax to run correctly and I am not sure why.

Here is the error log:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-edit" id="{{SubjectId}}" id1=" 
{{StudentId}}" >Edit</button>
```

JavaScript AJAX code:

```
$('.btn-edit').off('click').on('click', function () {
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        var id1 = parseInt($(this).attr('id1'));
        ExamsController.LoadDetail(id, id1);
    });

LoadDetail: function (id, id1) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Exams/LoadDetail',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id : id,
            id1 : id1
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.status);
            if (response.status == true) {
                var data = response.data;
                $('#txtSubjectName').val(data.Subject.SubjectName);
                $('#txtStudentName').val(data.Student.StudentName);
                $('#numScore').val(data.Score);
            } else {
                alert("Error!")
            }
        },
        Error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
},
```

And ExamsController

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult LoadDetail(int id, int id1)
{
    bool status = false;
    Exam exam = new Exam();
    exam = db.Exams.Find(id, id1);
    status = true;

    return Json(new
    {
        data = exam,
        status = status
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: If you copy/paste the url to the browser, do you get errors?

Comment: It still error, i think because i dont have parameters in url

Comment: Right, if you get rid of the 500 error in the browser, your ajax will work.

Comment: `/Exams/LoadDetail` is this the complete URL you trying to consume ? Also check developer tools --> network tab and see wether you are hitting right URL.

Comment: When i click button [Edit], it show log: [jquery-3.3.1.js:9600 GET http://localhost:49846/Exams/LoadDetail?id=1&id1=2 500 (Internal Server Error)]. When i check on network tab, this error [A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Exam]. Sorry. it is first time i use Stackoverflow and my format is too bad

Comment: If you're getting a circular reference then you need to see what's causing that.  That's probably your actual issue.

Comment: Year. I did it 1 minutes after, but still error.
This time, error is:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SubjectName' of null

Comment: I think that your data is not correct, please hard code your data like { 'id':'1','id1':'2'} for testing, your logic looks correct.

Comment: Can you provide model contents of `Exam`, `Subject` and `Student` entities? Rather than serializing directly like that, I preferred using viewmodel and pass it as AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

Internal server error means you have error in C# script, please double check error logs.
And also your code isnt cleanest, missing semi-colons.
Try add semi-colons, add name to function , and check error log, it can be useful, we can make better answer.
Maybe try this code with semi colon :) :

```js
$('.btn-edit').off('click').on('click', function () {
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
        var id1 = parseInt($(this).attr('id1'));
        ExamsController.LoadDetail(id, id1);
    });

LoadDetail: function (id, id1) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Exams/LoadDetail',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id : id,
            id1 : id1
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.status);
            if (response.status == true) {
                var data = response.data;
                $('#txtSubjectName').val(data.Subject.SubjectName);
                $('#txtStudentName').val(data.Student.StudentName);
                $('#numScore').val(data.Score);
            } else {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        },
        Error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
},
```

Thanks!

Comment: All good advice (or so it seems, although I don't know C#) - but this should be a comment because it's not actually an answer.